# Verify optical disks quality and integrity

Tags: optical-media, data-verification

I use optical media to do a backup of my data, mostly videos, I usually burn these CDs/DVDs/BDs using Nero and run SecurDisc surface scan at the end, but since it is not known [if it can be run again](https://superuser.com/q/1482320/939885), I need a solid way to know the integrity of my data. Many online sources pointed toward Nero DiscSpeed but it is no longer developed and gives an unsupported file system for disks burned using the UDF file system, so any recommendations for a tool to verify the state of the disk.

Preferably, the software should run on Windows but I'm also open to quite good Linux software; as for the price I'll just have to se to decide.